# Bootstrap list group item place button to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following: 
[image]

How do I place a button close and to the right of the elements? (aligned to be on the Name level)

**html**

```
<div class='list-group-item flex-column disabled'>
  <span class='circle'></span>
  <p class='name'>Name</p>
  <button id="test" type="button">Reject</button>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.circle {
    display: table-cell;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #c7c7c7;
}

#test {
    float:right;
}

.name {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

I want to have this:
[image]
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5aLv0so/3/)

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @sol bootstrap 4. I added tag to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Flex Utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) included with Bootstrap 4.

Add `.d-flex` and `.align-items-center` to the container.

Finally, `p` has a `margin-bottom` by default. Remove this to ensure it is vertically centered. Update the left and right margins to add spacing.

```css
.circle {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #c7c7c7;
}

.name {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class='list-group-item d-flex align-items-center disabled'>
  <span class='circle'></span>
  <p class='name'>Name</p>
  <button id="test" type="button">Reject</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you place the button closer? I added pic of desired result

Comment: @trthhrtz Updated